# Nested Excel Pivot table in python(pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I tried many times to get an output as the one in the picture attached. I'm looking for your help to make this work. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'Owner':['Brian','Andy','Paul'],
    'Areas':['BandA','Uat','Research'],
    'Title':['MS','Unix','Linux'],
    'DNS':['test','abc','production']
    })

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Areas'],values=['Title'],aggfunc='count')
df.to_excel('out.xlsx')
```

The expected result is an Excel file(xlsx) that looks exactly the same as this picture:
[image]

What should be added to my code to get the expected pivot table? Thank you!

Update! This is the expected result when running the script in cmd. Because each Owner has 1 Area, 1 Title and 1 DNS the total is 1 for each owner. If Brian had another system in another Area, with another Title and DNS the Count of title for him has two this time. And the Grand Total will be 2(from Brian) + 1(from Andy) +1(from Paul), that is 4.

```
        Count_of_title
Andy        1
Uat         1
Unix        1
abc         1

Brian       1
BandA       1
MS          1
test        1

Paul        1
Research    1
Linux       1
production  1

Grand total 3
```

Comment: So what does your code you've done so far do?  Do  you get errors?  Do you get a pivot table but not with the desired layout?

Comment: The question was updated! Makes more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Not exactly same (*visually*) as I am not sure if that is possible with pandas but the below code will yield the same result (*numerically*):

```
g = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Owner','Areas','Title','DNS'])['Title'].count().rename('Count').reset_index())
g.loc['Grand Total'] = g.sum(numeric_only = True)
g = g.fillna('')
print(g)

             Owner     Areas  Title         DNS  Count
0             Andy       Uat   Unix         abc    1.0
1            Brian     BandA     MS        test    1.0
2             Paul  Research  Linux  production    1.0
Grand Total                                        3.0
```

Comment: How can I add a "grand total"  cell ?